# nodemon not running due to requires update notifier package

Tags: node.js, nodemon

When I typed "nodemon server.js" command in the terminal, it returns the error "require('update-notifier')({ pkg }).notify();". The version of nodemon installed is nodemon@1.17.3

[image]

Below are the javascript and html used.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8888;

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log('Server running at port ' + port);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My NodeJS Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I updated the node version, it's now working. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, out of curiosity, which node version were you using?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande i didn't take note of the version that i was using. Is it possible to retrieve it?

Comment: Maybe it is, but it isn't worth the trouble, glad it worked out though, cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That error is telling that your node version does not support object literal property value shorthand, which was introduced in node 4, which is the [required version](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/8637e52dd1d39c8755f1e621dda0ba9487e5f88f/package.json#L12) for nodemon.

You should update your node version, since it's not a nodemon issue.

To provide further proof, executing nodemon on a docker container with node 0.12.15 installed trigger that exact same error.

**Node 0.12.15**

[image]

And it doesn't happen on node >= 4

[image]

**I recommend updating your node version to 8.11.1 which is the current LTS**

---

If you can't upgrade your node version (which you should), you can downgrade nodemon to version 1.11.0 which runs on node >= 0.8.

[image]

Comment: Hi! I'm having the exact same error, except my node version is the latest version and it still doesn't work...